# How to avoid act() with sub component changes?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, patternfly

I'm using the [Select component from patternfly](https://www.patternfly.org/v4/components/select/) and attempting to do a test that involves making changes to the selection. I feel like I'm in a catch 22 as I can make the tests pass without the `use act()` messages if I do this:

```
  await waitFor(() => {
    userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(labelText));
  });
  userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole('option')[optionNumber]);
```

however, I then get a lint error saying `Avoid using side effects within 'waitFor' callback`

If I remove the `waitFor()`, and do

```
userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(labelText));
userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole('option')[optionNumber]);
```

My tests give me the console errors saying `Warning: An update to Popper inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

One point worth noting, I'm only having this issue if I'm appending what ends up being the "Popper" menu (where the options reside) to `document.body` (or anywhere other than "inline") using the `Select` component's `menuAppendTo` prop. I have to do this to prevent some clipping issues with the menu being in a modal.

For now I'm just ignoring the lint issue:

```
 await waitFor(() => {
   // eslint-disable-next-line testing-library/no-wait-for-side-effects
   userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(labelText));
 });
 userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole('option')[optionNumber]);
```

How can I satisfy both the test and the lint?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by putting an await on a findBy for the options prior to clicking them, like so:

```
userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(labelText));
const options = await screen.findAllByRole('option');
userEvent.click(options[optionNumber]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I fixed the issue by updating testing-library/react in to version 14.0.0

> "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0"

For detail explanation you can see this article [Testing React components that update asynchronously with React Testing Library](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/testing-async-components/)